# Angular datetime picker?

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I can find plenty of datetime pickers for AngularJS but no reliable (working) ones for Angular. Is there any Angular datetime picker that works, that someone here has used?

Comment: Have you tried UI bootstrap calender this works for both. AngularJS And AngularJS 2. U need to modified youe code little bit.
for reference refer this link:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZGl0VuJjVF1nliMidaL6?p=previe.

Comment: @Yasin is there anyway to add time picker for this calendar ?

Comment: I have added into 1 datetime picker component https://github.com/Gillardo/ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup

Answer (score 2):

Try Calendar control from primeNG. This gives you any format of date & time.

Sample implementation looks like below-

Update package.json

```
"primeng": "^1.0.0-beta.7", "primeui": "^4.1.10",
```

component lines are-

```
import { Calendar } from 'primeng/primeng';
directives: [Calendar]

p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date1" dateFormat="mm/dd/yy" timeFormat="HH:mm">
```

You can find more format examples on - http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

Comment: Is it free to use in production?

Comment: All PrimeNG widgets are open source and free to use under MIT License.

Comment: Ok thanks! I updated the package json and on running npm update it gave an error like: npm ERR! shasum check failed for /tmp/npm-4892-b82ffbcf/registry.npmjs.org/primeui/-/primeui-4.1.15.tgz.

Comment: Can you please raise a new question with all your details?

Comment: Ok sure! I'll do it.

Comment: I got it to work but design is broken. Can you help! I have raised a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44536981/primeng-calender-displayed-with-broken-design-in-angular-2

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but i have made a basic popup component using the ngx-bootstrap datepicker and timepicker.  You can find it here

https://github.com/Gillardo/ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup

Comment: can you please add a demo?

Comment: This has been updated today and working on ng-cli, webpack etc with angular 4+

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used these libraries yet but both may help you:

[mydatepicker](https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker)

[ng2-datepicker](https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-datepicker)

Give them a try and let us know if they work correctly for Angular 2.

Comment: Ive already tried both. If you get their source code from github as is and try npm install and npm run, neither one works. mydatepicker fails in npm run and ng2-datepicker throws a javascrippt error and fails.

Comment: It's difficult to find libraries working since Angular 2 is still under development. If you use Chrome and an input of type date, a calendar button is shown and it works like datepicker, but only works on Chrome I guess.