# PrimeNg calender displayed with broken design in angular 2

Tags: angular, primeng

I have used primeNg module from primefaces in angular 2 for creating a timepicker. I got it to work but it is displayed with broken design. Is there anything else to add for getting the design correct. Codes I used:

package versions:

```
"primeng": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
 "primeui": "^4.1.10"
```

Module.ts:

```
import { CalendarModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
imports: [CalendarModule]
```

Html:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value" showTime="showTime" formControlName="date1" hourFormat="12"></p-calendar>
```

Currently what i get is:

[image]

Please help!!

Comment: Click the primefaces tag under your question. Read the text, do you actually use that?

Comment: Sorry for that. Primefaces are the creators of this module. Thats why. Will remove the tag.

Comment: No, PrimeTec is the creator of the module. They just 'share' the website (which causes confusion).

Comment: Oh! Okey. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include css dependencies in your index.html-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
```

For more information, refer setup guide [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup).

Comment: Yeah! I had done it already and got it working! Anyways thanks man. I will accept the answer.

Comment: I have added that. But, still facing TIME UI is broken.